# Python - randomint() should be equal to C - rand()

Tags: python, c, random

I have the following C - Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("%d", rand());
}
```

And this Python script:

```
import random
import time
random.seed(int(time.time()))
print (random.randint(0, 2147483647))
```

RAND_MAX in the C-program is defined as 2147483647. If I start both programs in the same second, they should print the same "random" number but this is not the case?

Any ideas why? Are there different methods implemented to get a pseudo-random number? The seed is definitely the same.

Comment: what makes you think that they're implemented the same way?

Comment: [Python's `random` module](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/_randommodule.c) appears to implement some version of the [Mersenne Twister RNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister).  Your C library either uses a different version of this RNG, or some other RNG entirely.  That's all there is to it.  There are _dozens_ of random number generation algorithms; it would be more surprising to me if this test "succeeded".

Comment: An easier way to test this is to seed with a constant rather than time. Just use `seed(0)`.

Answer (score 7):

The random number generator of C is not standardized at all. The C11 standard revision notes in [the footnote 295](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note295) that

> There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence produced and some implementations are known to produce sequences with distressingly non-random low-order bits. **Applications with particular requirements should use a 
>   generator that is known to be sufficient for their needs.**

Python is one of those applications: Python chose to use the [MT19937-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) random number generator, a.k.a. Mersenne Twister. It is very unlikely that a C library would use MT19937-32 for the `rand` implementation, and with the same seeding routine.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing they guarantee is that you will get a pseudo random number. You have basically no guarantees of how it will work.

Even if you compile the same C program on two different compilers, you're not guaranteed the exact same result when calling `rand()`.

You are basically wondering why you don't get the same result when rolling two different dice even if you roll them the exact same way. Well, they are different, and so is the result.